# sympy simplifying fractional powers of imaginary number

Tags: python, sympy

Why doesn't `-(-1)**(1/3) + (-1)**(2/3)` reduce to -1?

[wolfram alpha knows](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%28-1%29%2a%2a%281/3%29%20%2b%20%28-1%29%2a%2a%282/3%29&t=ietb01) it's -1 but [sympy gamma](http://gamma.sympy.org/input/?i=-%28-1%29%2a%2a%281/3%29%20%2b%20%28-1%29%2a%2a%282/3%29) only does a float approximation

`re(_) + I*im(_)` produces a `NegativeOne` object, but none of the other simplification functions I tried did anything to it.

Comment: Rounding error. If you want to know exactly what happens, check the SymPy source code.

Comment: @larsmans: but sympy doesn't have rounding error?

Comment: It does when it evaluates ordinary Python expressions, which I suspect is the case here. It doesn't change the Python language, just adds to it.

Comment: @larsmans no it's a sympy expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you really mean `-(-1)**Rational(1, 3) + (-1)**Rational(2, 3)`, as literally `-(-1)**(1/3) + (-1)**(2/3)` is all Python (no SymPy), and evaluates numerically.

Most SymPy objects do not do any kind of nontrivial simplification automatically. The reason is that sometimes you might want to represent `-(-1)**(1/3) + (-1)**(2/3)` without it simplifying. Also, simplification in general is an expensive operation, and doing so at operation creation time would be very inefficient, as often you create intermediate expressions that don't need to be simplified at the intermediate stage.

`re(expr) + I*im(expr)` is fine. A more automated way to do that is to use `expand_complex()`:

```
In [19]: expand_complex(-(-1)**Rational(1, 3) + (-1)**Rational(2, 3))
Out[19]: -1
```

Ideally `simplify()` would call `expand_complex()`, and there is an open issue for this (https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/7569).

And a note that SymPy Gamma provides a lot of automation on top of SymPy directly. For instance, it converts `-(-1)**(1/3) + (-1)**(2/3)` to SymPy types and performs various functions to the expression, like numerical evaluation, simplification, differentiation, etc.

Comment: Ah.  I tried a bunch of simplification functions but didn't find `expand_complex()`.